# Internet Explorer 11 beta in Windows 7: where's the compatibility mode?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Maybe it's a problem of this early revision, maybe it's because the new Developer Tools are giving me dizziness (and the Network panel crashes), but I can't find a way to set the compatibility mode in Internet Explorer 11 beta for Windows 7.

And I don't mean the ability to emulate just IE7, but also all the versions between the current and IE7, like IE8, IE9 and IE10 allowed to do.

Has anyone else had more luck?

**UPDATE 2013-11-30**: so there's this 'Emulation' part to do the trick. The problem is that's not a perfect emulation - even worse than IE9-10, as Trident isn't downgraded while emulating. So, for example, conditional comments don't work at all when emulating IE5-9.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the top part of the IE window. Click on the command bar option to show it. After, expand the Tools menu entry and select Compatibilty View Settings.

In fact, if you try to find this option via the tools icon near the favorites icon, the option  isn't available.

Comment: That's similiar to Tiago's answer, but what I'm looking for is  a way to select *which* compatibility mode to use, i.e. if using the IE7's render engine, or IE8 and so on. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 seems to not be able to properly detect if a website requires compatibility mode or not. So before when you needed to manually do it you could just press the Tool icon at the top right and click compatibility mode from there and just add your site to the list.

Comment: There's no compatibility mode in the tool menu. I guess you reported the answer [from here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11_pr-windows8_1_pr/is-internet-explorer-11-missing-compatibility-mode/e178b044-82ea-4c2d-aa52-c9d9867069b4), but it doesn't work for me, thanks.